# PHP array_chunk and then array_merge

Tags: php, arrays, merge

is there any way to merge undefined number of arrays? Array_merge doesn't work for me, cause you have to actually put those arrays as parameters, or maybe there is a way.

I've chunked an array into n - number of arrays, I do some stuff on those chunks and would like to merge some other arrays:

```
$chunky = array_chunk($positions);
$arraytomerge = array();
foreach($chunky as $key=>$val)
{
    do some stuff with $keys and $vals
    $arraytomerge[] = array('1','2','3','4');
}
$merged = array_merge($arraytomerge[0],$arraytomerge[1]...);
```

How to list arrays as array_merge parameters?

Comment: Why don't you want to insert elements into $merge array on every iteration?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing

```
//do some stuff with $keys and $vals
$arraytomerge[] = array('1','2','3','4');
```

Just do

```
//do some stuff with $keys and $vals
$merged = array_merge($merged,array('1','2','3','4'));
```

Or better yet, just add your new items directly to the $merged array instead of creating a new array

Comment: It's ok, but as for each loop array('1','2','3','4') contains different elements

Comment: You just replace array('1','2','3','4') with whatever the array is that you have on that loop. if your stuff is in $thisarray then just use $thisarray instead of array('1','2','3','4')